# UIImageView height and width changes after rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, transformation

Hey guys I've been trying to use two UISliders to manipulate one UIImageView. One slider to scale the image and one to rotate it. However, when I switch from one slider to the other it resets the previous rotation. (So if I scale the image to say 125x125 when its normally 100x100 and then go to use the other slider to rotate the image, it rotates it but changes its size back to 100x100 and vice versa). So anyways, Ive tried using CGAffineTransformConcat to combine the two transformations, Ive tried setting the frame of the ImageView after every transformation, I've tried deleting and readding the imageView to _myArray to "save" it, and I briefly tried using anchorpoints but all with no luck. So my question is, what am I doing wrong??? I feel like my code should work and each action shouldn't reset my UIImageView but I have no idea why it won't.

```
- (IBAction)scaleImage:(UISlider *)sender {
    NSLog(@"ScaleImage Called");
    UIImageView *selectedImage = [_myArray objectAtIndex:0];
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, sender.value, sender.value);
    selectedImage.transform = transform;
    _scaleValue = sender.value;
    //_width = selectedImage.frame.size.width
    //_height = selectedImage.frame.size.height
    _sizeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", _scaleValue];
}

- (IBAction)rotateImage:(UISlider *)sender {
    UIImageView *selectedImage = [_myArray objectAtIndex:0];
    //selectedImage.frame = CGRectMake(selectedImage.frame.origin.x, selectedImage.frame.origin.y, _width, _height);
    selectedImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(sender.value * 2*M_PI / sender.maximumValue);
    _rotationLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", _rotationValue];
    _rotationValue = sender.value;

}
```

Does anyone know why each method resets the others previous transformation.

Comment: Is your image view using auto layout?

Comment: Yeah and size classes if that matters

Comment: That could be the problem. Sometimes auto layout and transformations don't play well together. Try turning off auto layout, and see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your code, you will notice that you are explicitly setting the transform to the new value across the Identity transform.

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, sender.value, sender.value);
```

What you will want to do is apply the two together... you could save a rotation transform and a scale transform as properties and the IBActions would update those and then set the transform as a concatenation of the two.

So, the scale would look like:

```
self.scaleValue = sender.value;
```

And the rotation would look like:

```
self.rotateValue = sender.value * 2*M_PI / sender.maximumValue;
```

And you would have another method called transform

```
-(void)transform
{
    CGAffineTransform fullTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(self.rotateValue);
    CGAffineTransformScale(fullTransform, self.scaleValue, self.scaleValue);
    UIImageView *selectedImage = [_myArray objectAtIndex:0];
    selectedImage.transform = fullTransform;
}
```

You would then call that transform method in the IBAction calls at the end instead of trying to set the transforms separately

Comment: With a little tweaking this worked perfectly! I can't thank you enough, I've been trying to solve this for 6 hours… I ended up using `-(void) transform {
    CGAffineTransform fullTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(_rotationValue);
    CGAffineTransform fullTransform2 = CGAffineTransformScale(fullTransform, _scaleValue, _scaleValue);
    CGAffineTransform final = CGAffineTransformConcat(fullTransform, fullTransform2);
    UIImageView *selectedEye = [_eyeArray objectAtIndex:0];
    selectedEye.transform = final;
}`  For some reason your code wouldn't scale the image but this works fine!